# What is the meaning of hasSurface in SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

I find  many `SurfaceView` demos use hasSurface. But I can't understand it. What is the meaning of hasSurface? Is there anybody help me?

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements
  SurfaceHolder.Callback {

  private SurfaceHolder holder;
  private MySurfaceViewThread mySurfaceViewThread;
  private boolean hasSurface;

  MySurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    // Create a new SurfaceHolder and assign this
    // class as its callback.
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    hasSurface = false;
  }

  public void resume() {
    // Create and start the graphics update thread.
    if (mySurfaceViewThread == null) {
       mySurfaceViewThread = new MySurfaceViewThread();

       if (hasSurface == true)
         mySurfaceViewThread.start();
    }
  }

  public void pause() {
     // Kill the graphics update thread
     if (mySurfaceViewThread != null) {
       mySurfaceViewThread.requestExitAndWait();
       mySurfaceViewThread = null;
      }
  }

  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = true;
    if (mySurfaceViewThread != null)
       mySurfaceViewThread.start();
  }

  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = false;
    pause();
  }

  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                           int w, int h) {
    if (mySurfaceViewThread != null)
      mySurfaceViewThread.onWindowResize(w, h);
  }

  class MySurfaceViewThread extends Thread {
      private boolean done;

      MySurfaceViewThread() {
         super();
         done = false;
      }

     @Override
     public void run() {
       SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = holder;

       // Repeat the drawing loop until the thread is stopped.
       while (!done) {
         // Lock the surface and return the canvas to draw onto.
         Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
         // TODO: Draw on the canvas!
         // Unlock the canvas and render the current image.
         surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
      }

     public void requestExitAndWait() {
       // Mark this thread as complete and combine into
       // the main application thread.
       done = true;
        try {
           join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }

      }

     public void onWindowResize(int w, int h) {
       // Deal with a change in the available surface size.
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code of demo could be useful here where this hasSurface is used

Comment: well,i have added the demo code

Comment: Which version you are using? I don't see hasSurface in documentation.

Comment: " private boolean hasSurface;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot acquire the Canvas from the SurfaceHolder as long as the Surface is not yet valid. However, we can check whether the Surface has been created or not via the following statement:

```
boolean isCreated = surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid();
```

I assume hasSurface is similar to getSurface().isValid().

```
 @Override
 public void run() {


   SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = holder;

   // Repeat the drawing loop until the thread is stopped.
   while (!done) {
     if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
        continue;
     // Lock the surface and return the canvas to draw onto.
     Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
     // TODO: Draw on the canvas!
     // Unlock the canvas and render the current image.
     surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
  }
```

Comment: so it is not necessary?

Comment: You should use surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid(); before acquire Canvas from the SurfaceHolder. If you don't make sure Surface exists, you'll get exception when you try to call canvas related methods.

Comment: Instead of hasSurface in the run method after while check surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid() returns true then go ahead and execute the rest of the code. Otherwise call continue till surface is valid.

Comment: Did you read my code? Do you agree with me that hasSurface in resume is always false?

Comment: It depends on if onSurfaceCreated is called before resume or not, since onSurfaceCreated is the only place where hasSurface is set to true. I agree with you that in resume hasSurface will never be true. The thread needs to start for onSurfaceCreated to run, but thread depends on hasSurface to be true in order to start. Deadlock

Comment: thanke you. I have found when the hasSurace will be true. When we locked the screen,OnPause,OnStop will be called,but surfaceDestroy will not be called .And then we unlock the screen,the resume is called,the hasSurface is true.

Answer (score 2):

The Surface is created while the SurfaceView's window is visible so you need to know if your code can or cannot access it yet. You should implement `surfaceCreated()` and `surfaceDestroyed()` to be informed when the Surface is created and destroyed as the window is shown and hidden, so basically `hasSurface` (or whatever name you use) keeps the last known status of your surfrace for simplicity.

Comment: Is it  necessary？ let's look at the demo ,"hasSurface" is used in the  resume function, but I think hasSurface in resume is always false,will it be true?

Comment: SurfaceView is asynchronously handled and it is not not necessary always false as onResume is not called when nothing is already running

Comment: it is not not necessary always false as onResume is not called when nothing is already running???                                               sorry,  I'm not sure what you mean